# Page scroll bar freezes while div is updated by Ajax responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I'm using jQuery's $.ajax() to send Ajax request to server and bring back a large chunk of HTML content to replace the content of a div. Everything works fine except for the problem that while the div is being updated, the page is kind of frozen (even the vertical scroll bar is not draggable). It comes back to normal after the div is updated.

Anyone knows if this is desired behavior? (yes, the HTML content is a little big but not super big)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement a loader with a freezing background.

Answer (score 0):

Can you link your ajax code? I think you are doing a sync call, try setting async: true.

Still without the code thats all I can think about.